# Counting Occurrences from One Table and Inserting into Another but Getting an Error

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the amount of times each school shows up in a set of records and record that value in a new table with its corresponding school name and ID.

The tables being used are similar to the following:
Table 1-> school_probs

| school_code (pk, bigint) | school (text) | probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | school1 | Irrelevant info |
| 2 | school2 | ii |
| 3 | school3 | ii |

Table2-> simulated_records

| record_id (pk, bigint) | school (text) | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | school1 | ii |
| 2 | school2 | ii |
| 3 | school1 | ii |
| 4 | school3 | ii |

I'm expecting to get an output like

| school_code (fk, bigint) | school (text) | schoolCount (integer) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | school1 | 2 |
| 2 | school2 | 1 |
| 3 | school3 | 1 |

and I was able to achieve this with the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT (simulated_records.school) AS schoolCount, school_probs.school_code, school_probs.school
FROM simulated_records, school_probs WHERE school_probs.school = simulated_records.school
GROUP BY simulated_records.school, school_probs.school_code, school_probs.school;
```

However, I need the result to be saved in a table. But when I try

```
CREATE TABLE studentCount ( 
studentNum integer, school_code bigint, school text, 
CONSTRAINT fk_sC FOREIGN KEY (school_code) REFERNCES school_probs (school_code)
)
SELECT COUNT (simulated_records.school) AS schoolCount, school_probs.school_code, school_probs.school
FROM simulated_records, school_probs WHERE school_probs.school = simulated_records.school
GROUP BY simulated_records.school, school_probs.school_code, school_probs.school;
```

I get "ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 5: SELECT COUNT (simulated_records.school) AS schoolCount, . . . SQL state: 42601 "

Line 5 reads:
`SELECT COUNT (simulated_records.school) AS schoolCount, school_probs.school_code, school_probs.school`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I plan on creating a function out of this.

The code to create the tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS school_probs;
CREATE TABLE school_probs
(
  school_code bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  school text NOT NULL,
  probs numeric[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO school_probs VALUES
(1,'school1','{0.05,0.08,0.18,0.3,0.11,0.28}'),
(2,'school2','{0.06,0.1,0.295,0.36,0.12,0.065}'),
(3,'school3','{0.05,0.11,0.35,0.32,0.12,0.05}');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS simulated_records;
CREATE TABLE simulated_records
(
  record_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  school text NOT NULL,
  grade text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO simulated_records VALUES
(1,'school1','-'),
(2,'school2','-'),
(3,'school1','-'),
(4, 'school3', '-');
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images of code. THat makes it hard for someone to try out. Please edit the question and show the table definition as text.  Where is line 5?

Comment: PL/SQL is the procedural language extension for Oracle. It has nothing to do with the *SQL dialect* of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the `JOIN` syntax and don't use `,` in the `FROM` clause. Table aliases could also help.

And the syntax to create a table from a query is `CREATE TABLE <table name> AS SELECT ...`. There are no column or constraint definitions. You can use explicit casts in the query to determine column types. Constraint definitions have to be added later with `ALTER TABLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE studentcount
AS
SELECT count(sr.school)::integer studentnum,
       sp.school_code::bigint,
       sp.school::text
       FROM simulated_records sr
            INNER JOIN school_probs sp
                       ON sp.school = sr.school
       GROUP BY sp.school,
                sp.school_code;

ALTER TABLE studentcount 
            ADD CONSTRAINT fk_sc 
                           FOREIGN KEY (school_code)
                                       REFERENCES school_probs
                                                  (school_code);
```

Alternatively you can first issue a "normal" `CREATE TABLE` with column and constraint definitions and then insert the rows from the query.

```
CREATE TABLE studentcount
             (studentnum integer,
              school_code bigint,
              school text,
              CONSTRAINT fk_sc
                         FOREIGN KEY (school_code)
                                     REFERENCES school_probs
                                                (school_code));

INSERT INTO studentcount
            (studentnum,
             school_code,
             school)
            SELECT count(sr.school),
                   sp.school_code,
                   sp.school
                   FROM simulated_records sr
                        INNER JOIN school_probs sp
                                   ON sp.school = sr.school
                   GROUP BY sp.school,
                            sp.school_code;
```

But be aware that you're creating data redundancy either way. That can lead to inconsistencies and should be avoided. If you don't just need that temporarily but later again with then current values consider a view.

```
CREATE VIEW studentcount
AS
SELECT count(sr.school)::integer studentnum,
       sp.school_code::bigint,
       sp.school::text
       FROM simulated_records sr
            INNER JOIN school_probs sp
                       ON sp.school = sr.school
       GROUP BY sp.school,
                sp.school_code;
```